# Where is my Google Chrome theme stored locally?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome-extensions

On my Mac the `manifest.json` is not in the `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions` file folder. In fact this file path doesn't exist.

I have OS X Version 10.8.3

Answer (score 0):

I found the background images I was searching for in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Extensions
```

In that location a specific folder exists for each extension. Perhaps your file is in a similar directory.